# Tools/Script to reshape automaticaly topologic edges within a given distance in ArcGis 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, topology, tools

I have a footprint feature class and a land use cluster feature class. I am looking for a method/tool/script that would allow me:

1. to reshape two edges into one (topologically)
2. to decide at which distance it can be set
3. and to run the process automatically.

The outcome will be used into an hydraulic model, so it has to have the minimum amount of vertex as possible and still keep the main orthogonal shape of the footprint.

I have looked around and found some very interesting tools , although requiring a lot of manual editing.

Has anyone already see or used something similar?

---

First image shows the original Data (2 layers, so no gap to fill)

[image: width="50" height="50">]

The second image shows the first steps used toward the simplification of the footprint (red lines are original footprint): : Dissolve (No Multipart), Aggregate polygon (1 m distance and with option Keep orthogonal shape), simplify building.

[image]

The third image shows what I'd like to achieve although without the manual editing, I have here tried the Zipper tool: extension of one of side of a building'sfootprint to the next adjacent land use polygon (dark orange area show the extension).

[image]

Comment: This only helps with a part of your question, but have you looked into [Simplify Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//007000000011000000)? (ArcMap 10.0 help hasn't been working for me the past few days.)

Comment: I think adding a diagram (showing before and after) to this question would help.

Comment: Hi,<br/> thanks for the quick reply. I have used the following steps: Dissolve (No Multipart), Aggregate polygon (1 m distance and with option Keep orthogonal shape), simplify building. I have then tried the Zipper tool. The result is what I'd like to achieve although without the manual editing. <br/> @PolyGeo: html-newbie question: how can I insert pictures? <br/> Thanks for your quick answers

Comment: Your comment is difficult to follow but rather than try to improve its formatting could you simply edit your original question to "improve it at source", please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [Integrate tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002s000000) for realigning the two layer boundaries.

It allows you to set the maximum cluster tolerance (The distance that determines the range in which feature vertices are made coincident)  for the features and vertices to move.

It also allows you to add a "rank" to the featureclasses, which helps to keep the higher ranks "closer" to their original position, and move the lower ranked layers more.

Comment: I did try it but the result was not what I wanted as there is no "hole" between the footprint and the LU plots. Or maybe I gave wrong cluster tolerance. I'll try again. Thanks

Comment: Please post a picture of what you are hoping to achieve.  It will make it easier for everyone to get you the solution you are looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I finally manage this (Please, see original post).

Comment: I would try increasing your cluster tolerance.  Use something way too big at first (on temp datasets) just to see what happens, and try dialing it back to get your desired results.